# JSX element type 'Element' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So have a odd one here.
React functional component(FC) being rendered in another component.  The imported FC is the one with the type error, but has all the proper interfaces.

I have searched all the other posts related to this and none fit my use case.  They speak of optional components in the interfaces that case this, but I am not using this.  Also, I am render other FCs in the same class and they are not getting this error.  I am going crazy! Please help!

React 17.0.2

@types/react 17.0.6

imported component (has error)

```
...
<CreditCardDialog
   title={'Some String'}
   subTitle={`Some JSX string`}
   paymentAmount={'Some string'}
   verifiedOrganizationId={'Some string'}
   onSuccess={this.handleSuccess}
/>
...
```

Component Interfaces

```
export interface ICreditCardDialogProps extends withI18nProps, IWithStripeElements {
  paymentAmount: string;
  verifiedOrganizationId: string;
  onSuccess: () => void;
  title: string;
  subTitle: string;
}
```

Component

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  showToastr,
  toggleDialog
};

type Props =
  ICreditCardDialogProps &
  typeof mapDispatchToProps;

const CreditCardDialog: FC<Props> = (props) => {
...
}


export default compose(
  withI18n(),
  connect(null, mapDispatchToProps),
  withStripeElements
)(CreditCardDialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The FC did not like rendering a HOC.  I change it to a class even to test and still not good.  So I ended up passing them a props to the FC from the parent class component and it resolved this error.